# Calculate distance between two coordinate

Tags: java, coordinates

```
Coordinate 1 : 44.000, 61.001
Coordinate 2 : 44.000, 61.001
```

Here Coordinate are same so I expecting it will return zero distance. But they are returning below distance using below mention calculating formula.

```
Distance between two coordinates : 8.35023072909283E-8 (Means 0.0000000835023072909283)

Coordinate 1 : 110.000, 89.001
Coordinate 2 : 110.000, 89.001
```

Here Coordinate are same so I expecting it will return `zero` distance. But they are returning below distance using below mention calculating formula.

```
Distance between two coordinates : 1.5033016609322658E-7 (Means 0.00000015033016609322658)
```

For calculating distance I have used below code :

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coordinate2.getX() - coordinate1.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(coordinate2.getY() - coordinate1.getY(), 2))
```

Why above formula return `1.5033016609322658E-7` type of distance instead of `zero`?

> Note : All coordinates values are double.

Comment: formula seems is correct. are you using `double`? maybe use BigDecimal.

Comment: Read up on floating point precision and try to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` or `float`. This should remove or at least lessen precision issues.

Comment: How do you get these values? By subtracting the same longitude and latitudes, you should get a round 0.

Comment: [What every developer should know about floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Bifz "0.0000000835023072909283" **is** "around 0" depending on your definition of "around" ...

Comment: No, I meant round 0, like in whole.

Comment: @Bifz Missed the space ... :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're rounding the values of the coordinates to 3 decimal places while displaying them. The actual stored coordinates are *not* the same, due to some tiny accumulated floating point imprecision in whatever math you're using to calculate them. Since you're not rounding the distance when displaying that, you can see difference.

P.S. For tidiness of the code, you should wrap the distance calcutation up into a method on the `Coordinate` class. And [`Math.hypot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) is useful too:

```
public double distance(Coordinate c) {
    return Math.hypot(x - c.x, y - c.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `int`. e.g. 44.001 will become 44001 i.e. represent decimals such that there is no fractional part. Calculate distance using your formula and represent the ans. By multiplyimg suitable power of 10. E.g here, 10^[-3]

This will avoid errors associated with `float`.

Note. If integer representation creates very large no.s, think of using java `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid `BigDecimal` is using an integer representation.

If your decimal will never go beyond the 3th decimal digit, you can convert your coordinates to an integer representation by multiplying by 1000.
This way, your calculations don't lose precision.

Before returning any value, you need to re-convert it to the proper unit.
This logic should be encapsulated in your `Coordinate` class.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
 1. as asked before, it is better to use BigDecimal to calculate the distance.
 2. to calculate distances between to coordinates you have to take in account that they are over an sphere, not over a plane.